# MySQL order by index and then duplicates together

Tags: mysql, mariadb, sql-order-by

I want to have the rows sorted by ID and then have the duplicates appear sequentially.

Example:

```
id    color
1     red
2     green
3     yellow
4     green
5     green
6     red
```

Expected:

```
id    color
1     red
6     red
2     green
4     green
5     green
3     yellow
```

Comment: A simple `ORDER BY color,id` although that will get Green then Red then Yellow. Does that matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on MySql 8.0+ you can use MIN() window function:

```
select t.id, t.color
from (
  select *,
    min(id) over (partition by color) minid
  from tablename
) t
order by t.minid, id
```

For previous versions:

```
select t.* from tablename t
order by (select min(id) from tablename where color = t.color), id;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ivQJALrsgJE3mgp6927W7J/0).
Results:

```
| id  | color  |
| --- | ------ |
| 1   | red    |
| 6   | red    |
| 2   | green  |
| 4   | green  |
| 5   | green  |
| 3   | yellow |
```